# How can I maintain single copy of a 2d vector in clojure

Tags: clojure

I want to maintain a single copy of vector in whole class. I have to update vector many times in recursion.

```
 ;this is to update cell in vector
(defn to-plus [data x y]
 (update data y (fn [row] (apply str (assoc (vec row) x \+)))))

;here i am getting values in board and calling to-plus to update board
;now i need to maintain a single copy of board
(let [board (read-in-board "map.txt")]
(print-maze board)
(println(str (get-in board [1 4])))
(print-maze (to-plus board 1 4))
(println(to-plus board 1 4)))
```

I am trying to solve maze problem using recursion and random walk. I am new to Clojure.

```
;Data is of type 
---#--###----
-#---#----##-
####-#-#-#-##
---#---#-#---
-+-####---##-
-#------#----
-############
------------@
```

Comment: You can't. Clojure **vectors** are immutable. You can use Java-style **arrays**. Clojure has helper functions for these: [`make-array`][https://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/make-array] can make what you want. You can manipulate the arrray with `aget` and some form of `aset...`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update something in a tight loop, you can use a transient vector. [Docs here](https://clojure.org/reference/transients). They are designed to be "mutated" from a single Java Thread and turned into a persistent data structure before returning from your function. They are purely a performance optimisation over persistent vectors. Make your algorithm work first, then introduce transients to make it faster.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already answered, *Clojure* vectors are immutable. You have a few options,

1. Use a transient vector.
2. Use an atom.

Using a transient, your code will look like this,

```
(let [maze (transient [\* \* \* \*])]
  (assoc! maze
          1
          \#)
  (prn (persistent! maze)))
```

Using an atom, your code will look like this,

```
(let [maze (atom [\* \* \* \*])]
  (prn @maze)
  (swap! maze
         assoc
         1
         \#)
  (prn @maze))
```

This prints,

```
=> [\* \* \* \*]
=> [\* \# \* \*]
```

Note that when using an *atom*, the internal vector is still immutable. You are swapping the vector with a new vector each time. So if performance is your only concern, use *transient*.

If you want to update a deeply nested structure (think array of arrays), look at `assoc-in`.

Answer (score -1):

Use `to-array-2d` then `aget` and `aset`

**above answer got down voted by L.F.  Adding more detail below:**

“...maintain a single copy of vector...” 
Ans: Use `to-array-2d` to convert immutable nested-vector into mutable 2d array.

“...update vector many times in recursion...”
Ans: Use `aget` and `aset` to read and update the mutable 2d array created.